# How can I take datas from my database. MySQL and Python using

Tags: python, mysql

How can I take my datas from my database. I need to take random 50 items from my MySQL DB.

```
from random import randint
database = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=8080,  user="user", passwd="1234",database="a123")
cur = database.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT School  FROM  `a123`.`b123` randint 5   """)
database.commit()

prnt= cur.fetchall()
print(prnt)
```

it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is not true. Most important missing in your code, you forget the  import MySQLdb

```
database = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=8080,
                     user="user", passwd="1234", db="a123")
cur = database.cursor()

cur.execute("""
    SELECT 
        School
     FROM 
        `a123`.`b123` 
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 50;
""")
database.commit()

prnt = cur.fetchall()
print(prnt)
```

It must be work. It's a basic suggestion, you should fix the name of your db and table name.